Chainlink Functions Callback Error: One frequent reason for failure is too much gas being used
I'm currently developing a feature for my project that requires the use of a Chainlink function for the BlockMagic Hackathon. However, I'm encountering a callback error(see image) when using it. I have increased and decreased the gas limit.
enter image description here
I have tried with the following gas limits: 300000(max limit), 200000, 100000, and 3000. But I still get the callback error.
Please help.
Code: https://github.com/MiniMenu/Chainlink_functions_issue/blob/main/TriggerFunctionsConsumer.sol
sub link: https://functions.chain.link/polygon-amoy/250

I have noticed this happening on Amoy due to volatility...the callback gas limit of 300K may not be sufficient in that moment. Can you please try on sepolia or fuji ? the code appears ok but since Amoy is new it may be stabilising still.
